# How to put a timer for specific id on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to associate a timer on JavaScript to a specific id on HTML
how can i do this?
for example, setting a timer for `id=2`

```
<div class = "photos">
  <a3 id="1"> </a3>
  <a3 id="2"> </a3>
  <a3 id="3"> </a3>
  <a3 id="4"> </a3>
  <a3 id="5"> </a3>
  <a3 id="6"> </a3>
  <a3 id="7"> </a3>
  <a3 id="8"> </a3>
  <img scr=‪"C:\Users\User\Documents\banner(1).jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want? Show/hode that element based on timer?

Comment: yes, i want to hide this element

Comment: You should change those id's to start with letters, so you can use them with CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method of the *WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope* mixin (and successor to `Window.setTimeout()`) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

**Demo:**

```js
setTimeout(function(){ 
  document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none"; // hide the element after 3 seconds
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class = "photos">
  <a3 id="1"> 1</a3>
  <a3 id="2"> 2</a3>
  <a3 id="3"> 3</a3>
  <a3 id="4"> 4</a3>
  <a3 id="5"> 5</a3>
  <a3 id="6"> 6</a3>
  <a3 id="7"> 7</a3>
  <a3 id="8"> 8</a3>
  <img scr=‪"C:\Users\User\Documents\banner(1).jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert('Hello');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will change id=2 to id=25 after 3 seconds. check it:

```js
//please active console
    const divPhotos=document.querySelector('div.photos');
    console.log(divPhotos.children[1]);
    console.log('Now please wait for 3 seconds...');
    myFunction();
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            divPhotos.children[1].id=25;
            console.log(divPhotos.children[1]);
            }, 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none"; }, 3000);
```

Note : ***3000 is time by milliseconds***